# How to update a forked Jekyll GitHub blog from the original repository?

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I have a GitHub repository for a blog here: https://github.com/andrerpena/andrerpena.github.io.

This repository is a fork from this one: https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now.

What I'm trying to do is to update my repository based on the repository I forked from. I have no Git experience so I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/). But it's not working because it seems I don't have an `upstream` branch.

What do I do?

**EDIT**

After @sircapsalot's suggestion, it seems I now have the `upstream` branch properly configured:

[image]

Yet I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the CLI:

```
$ pwd
/users/.../andrerpena.github.io
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:barryclark/jekyll-now.git
$ git pull --rebase upstream master
```

The reason you don't have an `upstream`, is you didn't read :)

[image]

Go to that [that page](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/).

Comment: I appreciate your help. What exactly does the `rebase` command do? Does it switch my current branch from, let's say, `master` to `upstream`?

Comment: well, it varies.. sometimes you might want to do just a `merge` as the doc states.  But in this context, `--rebase` will do the following: `fetch from upstream master, make your current branch at the upstream master version, fast forward your commits onto the branch`

Comment: Thanks again. It seems I don't have permission to read from the remote directory: http://i.imgur.com/HigulLs.png. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: I followed the page you linked to and it seems my remotes are configured correctly: http://i.imgur.com/dpI0Gbj.png.

Comment: you might not have ssh configured properly.  Use `git remote add upstream  https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now.git` instead of `git@github.com...`. before doing that however, you'll need to remove `upstream` in order to add it again.  `git remote rm origin`, **then** `git remote add...`

Comment: Lol.. Damn it.. I ended up removing origin and not the upstream :)

Comment: Ok.. after I removed the `upstream` branch and then re-added it with `https` as you suggested.. the `rebase` worked.

Comment: as soon as I have time to go through this and test this out, I'll mark your asnwer as accepted.

Comment: did you get your `origin` restored?